# IBMBackendValueError: number of circuits exceeds the maximum for this backend, 300

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, pennylane

I am trying to run the QAOA on the IBMQ device. The QAOA circuit consists of 6 qubits, two layers. The number of total trainable parameters for the QAOA circuit is 14. The toy code is as follows:

```python
dev = qml.device('qiskit.ibmq', wires=args.dataset.n_node, backend='ibm_kyoto', ibmqx_token=token)
circuit = QAOA(dev)
opt_b = qml.AdamOptimizer(args.lr_qaoa)
param_b, loss = opt_b.step_and_cost(lambda param_b: circuit(param_b, circuit.param_c), circuit.param_b)
```

After running the code, it successfully ran on the IBMQ backend in the beginning by checking the IBMQ dashboard of my account. However, it soon raised the error `qiskit_ibm_provider.exceptions.IBMBackendValueError: Number of circuits, 418 exceeds the maximum for this backend, 300)`.
The detailed pennylane version information is listed in the following:

```
Name: PennyLane
Version: 0.35.1
Summary: PennyLane is a cross-platform Python library for quantum computing, quantum machine learning, and quantum chemistry. Train a quantum computer the same way as a neural network.
Home-page: https://github.com/PennyLaneAI/pennylane
Author:
Author-email:
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /home/yqia7342/qml/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: appdirs, autograd, autoray, cachetools, networkx, numpy, pennylane-lightning, requests, rustworkx, scipy, semantic-version, toml, typing-extensions
Required-by: PennyLane-qiskit, PennyLane_Lightning

Platform info:           Linux-5.15.0-58-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
Python version:          3.10.12
Numpy version:           1.26.4
Scipy version:           1.12.0
Installed devices:
- default.clifford (PennyLane-0.35.1)
- default.gaussian (PennyLane-0.35.1)
- default.mixed (PennyLane-0.35.1)
- default.qubit (PennyLane-0.35.1)
- default.qubit.autograd (PennyLane-0.35.1)
- default.qubit.jax (PennyLane-0.35.1)
- default.qubit.legacy (PennyLane-0.35.1)
- default.qubit.tf (PennyLane-0.35.1)
- default.qubit.torch (PennyLane-0.35.1)
- default.qutrit (PennyLane-0.35.1)
- null.qubit (PennyLane-0.35.1)
- lightning.qubit (PennyLane_Lightning-0.35.1)
- qiskit.aer (PennyLane-qiskit-0.35.1)
- qiskit.basicaer (PennyLane-qiskit-0.35.1)
- qiskit.ibmq (PennyLane-qiskit-0.35.1)
- qiskit.ibmq.circuit_runner (PennyLane-qiskit-0.35.1)
- qiskit.ibmq.sampler (PennyLane-qiskit-0.35.1)
- qiskit.remote (PennyLane-qiskit-0.35.1)
```

Could you please provide some advice on how to solve this issue?

Comment: It seems that the IBM backend is limiting the number of circuits that are submitted. Unless you plan to start tinkering with internal PennyLane or Qiskit code to streamline what's happening under the hood, your best bet from to reduce the number of generated circuits would be to use fewer parameters